# Higher-dimensional version of variance

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value, high-dimensional

If $X$ is a real-valued random variable,

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2$$

is the variance of $X$.

Suppose now that $X$ is a random variable that takes values on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider the quantity

$$f(x) = \mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2] - \|\mathbb{E}[X]\|^2,$$

where $\|x\|$ is the $L_2$ norm of the vector $x$: i.e., $\|x\|^2 = x^\top x = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$, and where $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is the coordinate-wise expected value of $X$, i.e., it is a $n$-vector whose $i$th component is $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$.  This looks like some kind of generalization of the variance to higher dimensions, where we replace "squaring a real number" with "the squared L_2 norm of a vector".

Is there some way to understand what the quantity $f(X)$ represents, or to get an intuition for what it is calculating?  Is it some generalization of the variance?

Answer (score 5):

It's just the sum of the variances of each component.

Suppose $n=2$ and $X=(X_1,X_2)$.  Then

$$\mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2] = \mathbb{E}[X_1^2 + X_2^2] = \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] + \mathbb{E}[X_2^2].$$

Also

$$\|\mathbb{E}[X]\|^2 = \|(\mathbb{E}[X_1],\mathbb{E}[X_2])\|^2 = \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2 + \mathbb{E}[X_2]^2.$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\|X|^2] - \|\mathbb{E}[X]\|^2
&= 
 \left( \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] - \mathbb{E}[X_1]^2 \right)
+  \left( \mathbb{E}[X_2^2] - \mathbb{E}[X_2]^2 \right) \\
&= \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Var}(X_2).\end{align*}$$

Comment: I don't see why ||(E($X_1,$$ X_2$)||$^2$ =E[$X_1$]$^2$ + E[$X_2]$$^2$.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, it's because $\|(u,v)\|^2 = u^2 + v^2$ (by definition of the squared-norm).  Now plug in $u=\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ and $v=\mathbb{E}[X_2]$.  (Or did I go wrong somewhere?)

Comment: Suppose $X$ can take the values $(1,1)$ or $(-1,-1)$ each with probability $\frac12$.  I would have thought $\|X\| = 2$ with probability $1$ and so $\mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2] = 4$, while $\mathbb{E}[X] =(0,0)$ so $\|\mathbb{E}[X]\|^2=0$ making the difference $4-0=4$.  But the sum of the variances is $1+1=2$

Comment: @Henry, no, in your example $\|X\|=\sqrt{2}$ and $\|X\|^2 = 2$.  Remember, $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L_2$ norm, and $\|\cdot\|^2$ is the squared $L_2$ norm, given by $\|x\|^2 = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2$, or in the case of $n=2$ dimensions, $\|x\|^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2$.  Therefore $\|X\|^2=2$ and $\mathbb{E}[\|X\|^2] = 2$, making the difference 2 -- which is equal to the sum of the variances.

Comment: I agree with D.W. answer now and think he can say it is related to variance in the sense that it is the sum of variances.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think $f(x)$ has any meaning, and absolutely it is not generalization of variance. The generalization of variance is variance-covaviance matrix defined by

$E(XX')-E(X)E(X)'$  where $X$ is random column vector.

Comment: If $X$ is random vector then $\Sigma = \operatorname{E}(XX')-\operatorname{E}(X)\operatorname{E}(X)'$ is indeed the covariance matrix and generalizes the notion of variance to random vectors. What the OP appears to be interested in is $\operatorname{E}(X'X)-\operatorname{E}(X)'\operatorname{E}(X)$ which is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Matthew Gunn. It does have a meaning and it is interpretable as a measure of 'total dispersion' (i.e. sum of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix), which to my mind is *a* generalisation of variance. Of course the covariance matrix contains more information, but the familiar one-dimensional variance is a special case of OPs 'variance', hence it's a generalisation.

Comment: If limited in New York City, you can say it is flat. When you generalize it to the world, ....... The covariance matrix is the perfect generalization of variance. Why we do not use it, instead to create an imperfect one. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, $f(x)$ is the variance of $X_1+X_2$. If they are not independent, what is $f(x)$? Suppose their correlation is 0.9, the information (or variation) that $(X_1,X_2)$ have is much less than $f(x)$.  Also, $f(x)$ is the trace, not sum of eigenvalues.

Comment: The trace is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, isn't it? I'm not denying that the covariance matrix is more informative than $f$. I'm just saying that it is a measure of dispersion and it has the 1D variance as a special case. Why does the mean exist when we can just look at the whole distribution? Because sometimes that's all we need.

Comment: Yes, I am wrong, trace = sum of eigenvalue.

Comment: But I still think $f(x)$ will mislead the people when $X$ are not independent if we consider it as the generalization of variance. If you insist on one number to reflect the variation of $X$, I prefer the $Var(\sum(X))$ over $f(x)$.